# Satisfaction of $\Delta_0$ formula for proper class

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I'm reading Kanamori's book on large cardinals, and on page 6 he defines truth of $\Delta_0$ formula for transitive proper class M as follows,
$\vDash^0_M$ $\phi[x_1,...,x_k]$ iff $\phi(v_1,...,v_k)$ is $\Sigma_0$ and $\exists$ $y\in M$ ($y$ is transitive & $x_1,...,x_k$ $\in$ $y$ & $ \langle y, \in\rangle$ $\vDash \phi[x_1,...,x_k]$ )
My questions are

(1) Why do we require $y \in M$? Because of the absoluteness of $\Delta_0$ formula, isn't the fact that there is some such $y$ sufficient?

(2) Isn't the requirement that $y \in M$ too strong? In general, given that $x_1,...,x_k$ in $M$ and that  $\phi^M[x_1,...,x_k]$, how do we infer that there is some $y \in M$ so that $x_1,...,x_k$ are in $y$?

I think I may be missing something simple. Thank you for the help!

Comment: The benefit of letting $y\in M$ is that we can internalize the definition of $\models^0_M$ to $M$ for a proper class model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZF}$. For your second question, the existence of such a set follows from $\mathsf{KP}$. (A weaker subtheory of $\mathsf{KP}$ would suffice, though.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! From the context he seems to be saying that M is any transitive class, but then the definition does not necessarily internalize & such a y does not necessarily exist, does it?

Comment: I think letting $y\in M$ would suffice to secure the internalizability of the truth predicate, but the existence of such $y$ is not guaranteed for general classes. It would be safe to assume that $M$ satisfies some fragment of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and I believe this is what Kanamori intended.

Comment: Just to clarify, by internalizing the predicate you mean the predicate relativized to $M$ with $\phi$ relativized to y) is equivalent to y satisfying $\phi$, right? Then indeed it can be internalized as long as $M$ is transitive

Comment: You are right, although I have not thought about such a detail.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! I have learnt a lot from your answers in this site!